# Why would installing one unity-scope remove ubuntu-desktop?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I wanted to install `unity-scope-github` but was faced with a surprising

```
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
session-shortcuts
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-desktop unity unity-scope-home unity-tweak-tool
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  unity-scope-github
```

Now this is probably a bug in some old/not actively maintained package which will be reported as soon as I have understood the issue.

My real question: How can I see why `apt` reaches the conclusion that **installing** one additional scope requires the **removal** of two useful meta-packages and `unity-scope-home`.

Is this an indication of problems in the database?

---

Annotation: `session-shortcuts` is only "no longer required" when I try to install `unity-scope-github`, before this `sudo apt autoremove` yields no result at all.

---

<sub>I know unity-scope-github is quite old/not actively maintained and I can and will live very well without it</sub>

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Install aptitude if you don't have it installed:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

Then run:

```
aptitude why-not unity-scope-github
```

It will give you an output like:

```
i   unity            Depends   unity-scope-home  
i A unity-scope-home Conflicts unity-scope-github
```

So we can see that `unity` depends on `unity-scope-home`, and `unity-scope-home` is in conflict with `unity-scope-github`.

The other packages of yours also are a part of these dependencies, e.g: if you run:

```
apt-cache depends unity-tweak-tool
```

You will find out that it depends on `unity` .

And about the `session-shortcuts`, If you run:

```
apt-cache rdepends session-shortcuts
```

You will get:

```
session-shortcuts
Reverse Depends:
  unity
  unity
```

That means this package was installed by unity, and now that unity is going to be removed, you no longer need it.

Comment: Great, another good use of `aptitude`! Additionally (comparing your output with mine) I found out about `apt-mark` (because I obvioulsly had issued something like `apt install unity-scope-home` some time in the past, so at first I did not get `A` in the `unity-scope-home` line and hence no `unity` line.

Comment: +1 I did know about `aptitude why`, but not about `aptitude why-not`...makes a lot of sense.